# Função não retorna valor com goroutines

Tags: golang

Boa tarde.

Eu possuo este codigo:

```js
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    urlU "net/url"
    "strconv"
    "math/rand"
    "strings"
)

func random(min, max int) int {
    return rand.Intn(max - min) + min
} 


var (
    err2 error
    body []byte
)

type requestResponse struct {
    err error
    body string
}

type requestOptions struct {
    url string
    method string
    body string
    headers map[string]string
}


func (options *requestOptions) doRequest() requestResponse {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        transport := &http.Transport{}

        proxyParse, _ := urlU.Parse("http://lum-customer-hl_5e2e538e-zone-static-session-" + strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(9999999)) + ":...@zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225")
        transport = &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyParse)}


        client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

        request, err := http.NewRequest(options.method, options.url, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(options.body)))

        if err != nil { continue }

        request.Close = true

        for headerField, headerValue := range options.headers {
            request.Header.Add(headerField, headerValue)
        }

        response, err := client.Do(request)

        if err != nil { continue }

        defer response.Body.Close()
        body, err2 = ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

        if err != nil { continue }

        if strings.Contains(string(body), "") {continue}

        break
    }

    return requestResponse{err: nil, body: string(body)}
}


func main() {


        for i := 0; i < 5; i ++ {

            myrand := random(000000, 999999)
            disparar(myrand)


        }

}

func disparar(myrand int){
    options := &requestOptions{
        url: "https://api...",
        method: "PUT",
        body: fmt.Sprintf(`{"code_2fa":"%s"}`,myrand),
        headers: map[string]string{
            "Authorization" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVkNWFmMjI4MTg0NzU5MDAxODdjZWJkZSIsInR5cGVMb2dpbiI6InVzZXIiLCJpc0FkbWluIjpmYWxzZSwiaWF0IjoxNTY5MzQwNzQxLCJleHAiOjE1NjkzNDE2NDF9.TgUcTTeh4cZIqmndRoBuULlPS0AiPExicXq0gTci_ac"},
        }

        retorno := options.doRequest()
        fmt.Println(myrand,retorno.body)
}
```

Estou tentando utilizar goroutines afim de agilizar o processo do script.

Quando eu adiciono `go` na linha `disparar(myrand)`, a função passa a não retorna nenhum o valor no console.

```js
func main() {


        for i := 0; i < 5; i ++ {

            myrand := random(000000, 999999)
            go disparar(myrand)


        }

}
```

Como posso disparar essas requests de modo assíncrono utilizando goroutines ?

Answer (score 2):

Quando você utiliza `go` na invocação da função, a função é executada em outro plano. O problema que você tem, é que a tarefa principal não espera pela execução de tarefas no segundo plano para finalizar o programa, quando a tarefa principal termina, o programa termina.

Então você precisa de alguma forma de sincronizar a tarefa principal com as tarefas em segundo plano, para esperar pela execução de todas as tarefas em segundo plano antes de prosseguir com a tarefa principal.

Você pode usar `channels`, ou o pacote `sync` para essa sincronização, exemplo:

```
func main() {
    // variável responsável por sincronizar as tarefas
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 5; i ++ {
        // sinaliza para esperar por mais uma tarefa
        wg.Add(1)
        myrand := random(000000, 999999)

        // função anônima imediatamente invocada que irá rodar em segundo plano
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, myrand int){
            disparar(myrand)

            // sinaliza que uma das tarefas terminou
            wg.Done()
        }(&wg, myrand)
    }

    // espera por todas as tarefas terminarem
    wg.Wait()
}
```